# Mysterious additional description about my site on Google search

Tags: search, seo, google-search

When I use Google search service, the result is somehow odd. Google adds this description below my website link,

> Enjoy the gaming fun by playing lots of games & win the exciting online casino uk, so keep playing. Many blackjack online games comes with exciting offers, the ...

But I never added this text no any part of the WordPress or... I don't know. Where does this text come from?

This is my website [link](http://sciself.com).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Its about Coding, No, Why off-topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this:

```
<!-- /all in one seo pack pro -->
<meta name="generator" content="Powered by Visual Composer - drag and drop page builder for WordPress."/>
<div id="caa7rt"><!--googleoff: snippet--> Enjoy the gaming fun by playing lots of games & win the exciting <a href="http://www.centralstationpub.com/?p=online-casino-uk" title="online casino uk">online casino uk</a>, so keep playing. 
Many <a href="http://www.studioweb.bg/?p=blackjack-online" title="blackjack online">blackjack online</a> games comes with exciting offers, the players want to grab the opportunity. 
Get the details of digital encryption system and other security features adopted by Vegas slots via <a href="http://witchsrocksurfcamp.com/?p=best-online-casino-2014" title="pokernews live reporting">pokernews live reporting</a>. 
<!--googleon: snippet--> <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("caa7rt").innerHTML = '';</script> </div><style type="text/css">.broken_link, a.broken_link {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}</style>
```